# What is the date format of 2019-06-17T20:27:23.706000000Z?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-format, dateformatter

What is the date format of `2019-06-17T20:27:23.706000000Z`?
I need date format of this format of dates, also need to parse and convert it to java Date.

I tried with this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

But, it's giving me incorrect results.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Your format is ISO 8601. Use `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Each of those will parse your string without any explicit formatter.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the info. Yes, i am using instant class which is way better than the legacy date-time classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        try{
            Date date = sdf.parse("2019-06-17T20:27:23.706Z");
            System.out.println(date);
        }
        catch(Exception pe){
            System.out.println(pe);
        }

    }
}
```

output:

```
Mon Jun 17 20:27:23 UTC 2019
```

By the way, you can also try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS'Z'");
```

Both gives the same result

Try using `Instant` from `java.time` package(java 8).

```
String value = "2019-06-17T20:27:23.706000000Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse(value);
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Comment: Thanks Anubav, if we use 2019-06-17T20:27:23.706000000Z it giving me result as  Wed Jun 26 00:34:03 PDT 2019 which is incorrect.. so it can only support 3 digits in miliseconds? is there a way to handle more than 3 digits?

Comment: Yeah, because Milliseconds(SSS) can only be three digits

Comment: check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: It seems to output strange/wrong results when we are adding more values after 3 digits

Comment: So you should use only 3 digits. After that value will start to change.

Comment: one quick question, the link u send https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. I have gone through it, but i couldn't see anything mentioned like only 3 digits are accepted for milliseconds. Am i missing something?

Comment: Go through this SO answer and comments, I think you will find the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926442/java-simpledateformat-pattern-parseexception/47926690

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I already included a solution from java.time package.